# Boxcox - error "cannot coerce xlass '"function"' to data.frame"

Tags: r

Hello I'm trying to deal with an error on my boxcox function, first I did an anova on my data frame, and now tha boxcox function is returning this error :

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

Here is my code :

```
setwd("D:/Emile/CLASSEUR/ENSAT-Cours/S8/UE 3 Semences et amélioration des plantes/DMs/DM n°1")
table <- read.table("PloidiePasteque.csv",sep=";", dec='.', header=T)

str(table)

#Mise en place du modèle
ana <- aov(table$Sugar ~ table$Genotype*table$Ploidy + table$Rep, data=table)

#Vérif normalité
shapiro.test(residuals(ana))

#homoscédacité Levene
summary(aov(abs(residuals(ana))~table$Genotype*table$Ploidy+table$Rep))

#Par boxcox
library(MASS)
boxcox(ana)
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me

Comment: Hi - Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you post your data please? With `dput(head(x))` where `x` is your data.

Comment: first you shouldn't use `$` in a formula, `aov(Sugar ~ Genotype * Ploidy + Rep, data=table)` is sufficient and cleaner. this appears to be a scoping issue as `update` finds the function `table` instead of your data frame (try `debugonce(update)` and run your `boxcox`). you can `boxcox(ana, data = table)` (this only works if you aren't using `$` in a formula, or change the name of your data frame to something that is not already an object

Comment: Yeah, I see, but the fact is that changing the name of the data set for "ploidie" did nothing and since I posted this question, I added :

attach(ploidie)

So now I don't use $ anymore.

Comment: i don't think that will work as `with(mtcars, boxcox(aov(mpg ~ vs * am + wt)))` throws an error but `boxcox(aov(mpg ~ vs * am + wt, data = mtcars))` works

Comment: Thanks for help everyone, I think there was some conflicts in my script with other elements, I restardted from the begining and now it's all fine.